# Autoit pause Start/stop hotkey

Tags: autoit

I have a script pushing "k" button in loop. I have added pause button on "q".
I also want "w" to pause the script. But I don want "w" to start my script. Is that possible?

```
Global $UnPaused
HotKeySet("q", "TogglePause")
HotKeySet("{PAUSE}", "TogglePause")
HotKeySet("{.}", "Terminate")

While 1
Sleep(100)
WEnd

Func TogglePause()
$UnPaused = NOT $UnPaused
While $UnPaused
    Send("k")
WEnd
EndFunc

Func Terminate()
Exit 0
EndFunc
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest rearranging your code & introducing a Pause() function to make things easier:

```
Global $UnPaused=false;
HotKeySet("q", "Pause")
HotKeySet("{PAUSE}", "TogglePause")
HotKeySet("{.}", "Terminate")

While 1
    if $UnPaused Then
        Send("k");
    Else
        Sleep(100)
    EndIf
WEnd

Func Pause()
$UnPaused = False
EndFunc

Func TogglePause()
$UnPaused = NOT $UnPaused
EndFunc

Func Terminate()
Exit 0
EndFunc
```

And if you don't want to capture a hotkey whilst paused, here's an example of that:

```
Global $UnPaused=false;
HotKeySet("q", "Pause")
HotKeySet("{PAUSE}", "TogglePause")
HotKeySet("{.}", "Terminate")
HotKeySet("w", "Pause")
While 1
    if $UnPaused Then
        HotKeySet("w", "Pause")
        Send("k");
    Else
        HotKeySet("w")
        Sleep(100)
    EndIf
WEnd

Func Pause()
$UnPaused = False
EndFunc

Func TogglePause()
$UnPaused = NOT $UnPaused
EndFunc

Func Terminate()
Exit 0
EndFunc
```

Comment: That works, only problem is that if i use "HotKeySet("w", "Pause")" the w button will not function as a normal.  When Im writing normal tekst the w-button does not work.

Comment: see the edit. use HotKeySet("w") to stop capturing w